# datepicker Bootstrap and cakephp

Tags: cakephp, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker Boostrap in my cakephp application (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) but, when I try to save the date (to POST) I never get this date by POST.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false); ?>
<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="Data do Registo" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>  
(...)
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#dp3").datepicker()
                .on('show', function(ev) {
            var today = new Date();
            var t = today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getFullYear();
            $('#dp3').data({date: t}).datepicker('update');
        });

        $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't get the datepicker field posted, or the value for that field is empty?

Comment: does not appears nothing in my Post ARRAY. Nothing related to datepicker.

on the other hand i use one bootstrap timepicker and these appears.

array(
 'hour' => '01',
 'minute' => '15',
 'projects' => '10003',
 'projectversions' => '',
 'clients' => '',
 'categories' => '',
 'comentarios' => ''
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're not using the FormHelper to display the date input to include all the classes necessary for datepicker bootstrap. If you have the Security component this will give you problems, but otherwise is ok, I guess... Although I recommend looking up [alternatives](http://drawrdesign.com/twitter-bootstrap-for-cakephp) to integrate both without having to miss the FormHelper -er- help.

But! you're missing the name of the input.
FormHelper adds a name to all inputs created by it. So check with firebug or the like what type of name the other input gets. It should be something like this

```
<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input name="data[FormName][datepicker]" class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="Data do Registo" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

And you'll get it in the action with

```
$this->request->data['FormName']['datepicker']
```

Comment: yes its true. thank you so much :)
I've tested it and it worked.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you get the chance. And also, do look into those alternatives to integrate bootstrap and cake, or a lot of this little issues are bound to appear :)